# Naming Excel Sheets automatically

Tags: export, excel, automation

After performing some calculations with excel sheets I end with a tridimensional matrix **a** to be export to a .xlsx format and a vector **q** that contains the name of all the sheets (so $Length[q] = Length[a]$).
In the documentation the usual way to export this named excel data is to do something like

```
Export["file name.xlsx", q[[1]] -> a[[1]], ..., q[[n]] -> a[[n]]] ]
```

But since the $Length[a]]$ is variable I do not know an automatic way to do that.
I tried something like

```
q -> a
```

But Mathematica can't process in this way.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You say `the usual way to export this named` and then the command says `Import`? Is this a typo?

Comment: Yes, thanks, @Nasser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
a = {{{1}}, {{2}}};
q = {"one", "two"};
Export["c:\\test.xlsx", Rule @@@ Transpose@{q, a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks, @belisarius. I was trying something more complicate. I need to use more the rule method. ^^